# Good six+ button wired or wireless left-handed Mouse for Boot Camped system?

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, mouse

I'm physically limited and **solely** have functional use of my ***left hand***.

I previously used a Razor DeathAdder Left Handed Edition and am now making do with a Logitech MX Anywhere 3 that has to be **set up as a new mouse *every time I reboot between OSes!*** Additionally, despite the manufacturer classing it as an "Ambidextrous" mouse the two side buttons are **only** on the left side!

I need a left handed or truely ambidextrous mouse that can be used in Mac and Windows mode ***without reconfiguration*** and also allows redefining button assignments in both Mac and Windows!

Comment: The issue of having to setup as a new mouse looks like a problem that would make a question and might bve able to be answered if you told us how you did the configuration - That should be a separate question.

Comment: Perhaps the Logitech could be configured for 'setting 1' on one OS & 'setting 2' on the other. That way it might identify each as a separate computer & you could switch between using the button underneath. [I have an MX, but this is something I've never needed to test, so idk if it would work exactly like this]

Answer (score 1):

Contour https://contour-design.co.uk/products/one-handed-mice/unimouse/ has left-handed mice but only 5 buttons and a scrollwheel which is also a button.

For the mac it needs no configuration. It does have a driver that allows some configuration.